# Why nodejs can make hardlink with dircortory?

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, hyperlink

os version:

```
➜  showlink sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.1
BuildVersion:   17B35a
```

before exec the script:

```
➜ showlink tree --inodes .
.
└── [9628588]  test
    ├── [9628740]  link.js
    └── [9628707]  src

2 directories, 1 file
```

nodejs script :

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
//i try to the dist at the same dir with src, but failed 
const dist = path.join(__dirname, '../dist')
fs.link(src, dist, (err) => console.log(err))
```

after:

```
➜  showlink tree --inodes  .
.
├── [9628707]  dist
└── [9628588]  test
    ├── [9628740]  link.js
    └── [9628707]  src

3 directories, 1 file
```

add some file

```
➜  showlink touch test/src/demo{1..3}
```

now:

```
➜  showlink tree --inodes  .
.
├── [9628707]  dist
│   ├── [9629200]  demo1
│   ├── [9629201]  demo2
│   └── [9629202]  demo3
└── [9628588]  test
    ├── [9628740]  link.js
    └── [9628707]  src
        ├── [9629200]  demo1
        ├── [9629201]  demo2
        └── [9629202]  demo3

3 directories, 7 files
```

when i search google 'hard-link' ,all answer show me that: the dir can't make a hard link . but ... node.js create the dir's hard-link (the number in Brackets is i-node number). what happened?
Thanks

Comment: I know, not an exact duplicate, but all the answer and details are all in there.

Comment: Basically it was added to OSX HSF for time machine backups. The `ln` doesn't allow it, but it's possible. That doesn't mean you should hard link dirs, it's still a bad idea.